# SQL request to get several prices by time in the past

Tags: sql

The table has 3 fields: `tickerId`, `time`, `price`
I want to get the latest prices for a given time `t` in the past for tickerIds `tIds = [tId1, tId2, ...]`
I understand how it can be done with separate request for each ticker, but is it possible with one request?

Merci

Answer (score 0):

One method is a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.ticketid in ( . . . ) and
      t.time = (select max(t2.time)
                from t t2
                where t2.ticketid = t.ticketid and
                      t2.time < ?    -- the time you care about
               )
```